# how to change bash tracing / verbose mode temporarily?

Tags: bash, shell-script

I use `-x` to trace bash script execution:

```
#!/bin/bash -x

x=1
y=2
```

during execution sends to output

```
+ x=1
+ y=2
```

the question: how in the middle of the script I can stop/pause tracing mode then enable it again? Pls note ti's NOT about something like y=2 >/dev/null.

Is it possible in verbose mode (`#!/bin/bash -v`)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`set` builtin](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#The-Set-Builtin) controls those options.

To turn `xtrace` on:

```
set -x
```

To turn it off:

```
set +x
```

That's a bit of an inverse logic with the plus and minus but there it is.

Similarly, all other options supported by `set` can also be set on the command line<sup>(*)</sup>, so `bash -u` does the same as `set -u` etc. There's a list of those in the linked description, and `help set` on the command line also shows them.

Some of the options have long forms too, e.g. `set -o xtrace` is the same as `set -x`.

(* We can't say that the other way around, though. Not all command line options can be set with `set`, e.g. `-l` has no equivalent, and neither does `-c`, obviously.)